# jCarousel that is fast in IE6, but utterly slow in IE7 (with transparent pngs)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, png, jcarousel

does anybody know if there is a high performance penalty in IE7 for animating semitransparent pngs?

I got a jCarousel that works awesome in webkit, so so in Firefox, and just deplorable in IE7. In IE6 it is very fast, surprisingly. I'm suspecting an isue with animating transparent PNGs.

Sorry, I don't have a test case online.

Comment: Unfortunately no. Depending on your design you might be able to serve jpg instead of png.